# Products Insert Problem

Tags: apex, soap-api, webservices, soap

Below is my webservice i would like to insert products before quotes insert may i know how can i do this. while i am doing it shows an error is-->variable Prods is not exist, below are bold lines which i was trying for product insert

```
      global class QuoteWrapper{
      webservice String qName;

     }

      global class ProductWrapper {
        webservice String pCode;
        webservice String pName;
     } 
     global class ResponseClass
     {
      webservice String errorMessage;
      webservice String resId;
      webservice String resName;    
     } 
     webservice static ResponseClass behaviourOfWebService(RequestClass req)
     {
       ResponseClass res = new ResponseClass();


            op = new Opportunity();
            op.Name = oName;
            op.CloseDate =system.today();
            op.StageName = oStage;
            op.accountId = id;
            oppList.add(op); 
           }
            Database.insert(oppList);  





        }**  i wrote the product for loop like this but it showing an error how can i write the for loop to insert products.


            qu = new Quote();
            qu.Name = qName;
            qu.OpportunityId=id;
            qList.add(qu); 
           }
            Database.insert(qList);  

        }
       }
         return res;
     }
}
```

Comment: @mastor i tried for product insert but it is not insert, so may i know how to insert products.

Comment: What products are you trying to insert?  Where does the list of products come from?

Comment: @jimRae i am inserting only productCode, Productname i can't understand how to insert products why because it is look up to quote, how can i insert that product values.

Comment: Do the products you are inserting already exist in Salesforce, or are you expecting to add them as new products?  If they exist, is the productCode an External ID (so you could reference it in your insert)?

Comment: @jimRae I am inserting new products.into sfdc.

Comment: Sathya, you have been asking variations of the same problem in 3+ posts that I have seen.  Please consider taking some time to read through the documentation on developer.force.com, blogs, the success community, et al for a better understanding of how DML, apex, configuration et al work together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things you will need to do to make this work.  First, you will need to create the products, based on your current coding pattern, you will need to add a ProductWrapper list to your AccountWrapper

```
global class AccountWrapper
 {   
  webservice String accName;
  webservice String accNumber;


 }
```

Then, you will need to upsert the products:

```
for(integer j=0;j<prods.size();j++)
    {
        p = new Product2();
            //need this to be an External ID            
            p.productCode = pCode; 

        p.name = pName;
        p.isActive = true;
        pList.add(p);  
    }
        Schema.SObjectField f = Product2.ProductCode;
        //use upsert and the External ID to prevent duplicate products
            Database.upsert(pList,f);
```

Next, you will need to add the products to the Standard pricebook (assuming you are only using the standard pricebook, otherwise, you will also need to create a PricebookEntry for the custom pricebook as well

```
ID stdPBid = [Select p.IsStandard, p.IsActive From Pricebook2 p 
               where p.IsActive=true and p.IsStandard=true LIMIT 1 ].id;

 List<PricebookEntry> PBEList = new List<PricebookEntry>();
 for(Product2 p:pList)
   {
     PriceBookEntry pbe = new PriceBookEntry();
     pbe.UseStandardPrice=true;
     pbe.UnitPrice=1;//Not sure how you are defining the price
     pbe.ProductCode=p.ProductCode;
     pbe.Product2Id=p.id;
     pbe.Pricebook2Id=stdPBid;
     pbe.Name=p.Name;
     pbe.IsActive=true;
     PBEList.add(pbe);
   }

   Database.Insert(PBEList);
```

Next, you will need to insert the OpportunityLineItems (these link the Product to the Opportunity

```
   List<OpportunityLineItem> OLIList = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();
   for(Opportunity o:OppList)
     {
        for(PricebookEntry pbe:PBEList)
         {
           OpportunityLineItem oli = new OpportunityLineItem();
           oli.UnitPrice=pbe.UnitPrice;//Unless you are pricing differently
           oli.Quantity=1;
           oli.PricebookEntryId=pbe.id;
           oli.OpportunityId = o.id;
           OLIList.add(oli);
         }
      }
     Database.Insert(OLIList);
```

Now, when you insert your quote, if you set the Sync flag to true, the OpportunityLineItems will get sync'd as Quote Line items.  I am adding this code all in the message, so it may need to  be touched up a bit to work correctly.

Comment: while inserting pricebook entry code it showing an error is Field is not writeable at  PricebookEntry.ProductCode May i know what i have to do.

Comment: I am getting an error while working with pricebook entry.May i know how can solve this.

Comment: i am getting error may i know why it's happen.

Comment: You will need to share more information.  What is the error you are getting?  How are you calling the webservice? Can you provide an example of how you call it and any debug log / error messages you are receiving?

Comment: Error which i was occuring is PricebookEntry.ProductCode

Comment: Try commenting out that line of code.

Comment: I tried as per u r suggestion but the products are not inserting in bulk, suppose if i get 2 accounts each account have 2 products at that time products are not inserting.may i know what i have to do.

Comment: What isn't working?  Does it work with one product?  Use the Developer console to monitor the service and add system.debug statements to see what  is happening

Comment: it's working fine how can i check for duplicate products.